# In-House Certificate Authority (CA) for Node.js https.request: How to point to .PEM?

Tags: node.js, https, certificate, ssl-certificate

I recently updated from Node 0.8.xx to 0.10.5.  Suddenly, my https.request calls started failing.  I believe 0.8.x was not verifying certificates, but 0.10.5 is.  We have some in-house certificate authorities set up to verify internal https traffic.  I would like to show Node.js https.request client the certificates.  How do I do this?

Currently, I'm getting:

```
Problem with request:  UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
```

I have tried:

```
var https_request_options = {
    host: 'myhost.com',
    path: '/thepath',
    port:  443,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'Content-length': thebody.length,
    },
    // rejectUnauthorized: false,
    ca: [fs.readFileSync('/whatever/path/ca_certs.pem')]
};

var authRequest = https.request(https_request_options, function(response) {
    ....
```

The calls work if I set `rejectUnauthorized: false`, but I'd like to start taking advantage of the improved security in Node 0.10.5.

I believe my .pem file is good because it works with Python httplib2 (${python}/Lib/site-packages/httplib2/cacerts.txt) and cURL ("curl-ca-bundle.crt").

Answer (score 0):

well, maybe these helps,

`/whatever/path/`  must be a relative folder of your proyect.